# explain binary_printf function [C lang]

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Can someone please explain the `binary_printf` function below?
What are `mask` and `shift` and how does it work in line:

```
byte = (value & mask) / shift; // Isolate each byte.
```

I think it is useless it always gives '0', And also explain the `if-else` statement `byte & 0x80`... altogether explain me the entire code? I got this code from  *Jon Erickson's* famous Book *Hacking: the art of exploitation.* Explain it in simplest words.

```
void binary_print(unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int mask = 0xff000000;       // Start with a mask for the highest byte.
    unsigned int shift = 256 * 256 * 256; // Start with a shift for the highest byte.
    unsigned int byte, byte_iterator, bit_iterator;
    for (byte_iterator = 0; byte_iterator < 4; byte_iterator++)
    {
        byte = (value & mask) / shift; // Isolate each byte.
        printf(" ");
        for (bit_iterator = 0; bit_iterator < 8; bit_iterator++)
        {                    // Print the byte's bits.
            if (byte & 0x80) // If the highest bit in the byte isn't 0,
                printf("1"); // print a 1.
            else
                printf("0"); // Otherwise, print a 0.
            byte *= 2;       // Move all the bits to the left by 1.
        }
        mask /= 256;  // Move the bits in mask right by 8.
        shift /= 256; // Move the bits in shift right by 8.
    }
}
```

Comment: Each line is commented - which don't you understand?

Comment: *`// Isolate each byte.` is useless it always gave '0'.* This isn't the case. If you `printf("%02X ", byte);` you see the correct value of each byte.

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop runs 4 times with values for `mask` and `shift` starting at `0xff000000` and `0x1000000`, then divided by 256 at the end of the loop body, hence becoming `0xff0000` and `0x10000`, then `0xff00` and `0x100`, then finally `0xff` and `1`.

The value of `byte` in the inner loop comprises the 8 bits of the most significant byte, then the byte after that, etc until the lower significant byte.

The inner loop runs 8 times, testing the most significant byte of the `byte` (`if (byte & 0x80)` is true if and only if the most significant bit is set in `byte`), and shifting all bits in `byte` left one position at the end of this loop.

It is confusing to name `shift` a value that is used as a divisor. As a matter of fact, it is unclear if the compiler will convert this division to a shift.

The code can be simplified using an actual shift operator this way:

```
void binary_print(unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int shift = 8 * 3; // Start with a shift for the highest byte.
    unsigned int byte, byte_iterator, bit_iterator;
    for (byte_iterator = 0; byte_iterator < 4; byte_iterator++)
    {
        byte = (value >> shift) & 0xff; // Isolate each byte.
        printf(" ");
        for (bit_iterator = 0; bit_iterator < 8; bit_iterator++)
        {                    // Print the byte's bits.
            if (byte & 0x80) // If the highest bit in the byte isn't 0,
                printf("1"); // print a 1.
            else
                printf("0"); // Otherwise, print a 0.
            byte *= 2;       // Move all the bits to the left by 1.
        }
        shift -= 8; // reduce shift amount for the next byte
    }
}
```

It is also confusing to call `byte` an `unsigned int` that may have a value that does not fit in a byte. It would be more consistent to use a `mask` starting at `0x80` and shifting it right by one position after each iteration and use `if (byte & mask)` to test each bit.

With this approach, you can actually avoid extracting the bytes and use a 32-bit `mask` for a single bit, shifting in the inner loop:

```
void binary_print(unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int mask = 0x8000000000; // Start with a mask for the highest bit.
    unsigned int byte_iterator, bit_iterator;
    for (byte_iterator = 0; byte_iterator < 4; byte_iterator++)
    {
        printf(" ");
        for (bit_iterator = 0; bit_iterator < 8; bit_iterator++)
        {                    // Print the byte's bits.
            if (value & mask) // If the bit in the byte isn't 0,
                printf("1"); // print a 1.
            else
                printf("0"); // Otherwise, print a 0.
            mask >>= 1;      // Skip to the next bit.
        }
    }
}
```

You can remove the inner loop and use a test to output a separator every 8 bits:

```
void binary_print(unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int mask = 0x8000000000;     // Start with a mask for the highest bit.
    unsigned int bit_iterator;
    for (bit_iterator = 0; bit_iterator < 32; bit_iterator++)
    {
        if (mask & 0x80808080)  // output a space every 8 bits
            printf(" ");
        if (value & mask)    // If the bit in value isn't 0,
            printf("1");     // print a 1.
        else
            printf("0");     // Otherwise, print a 0.
        mask >>= 1;          // Skip to the next bit.
    }
}
```

Using `bit_iterator` and `mask` is actually redundant. Here is a further simplified version:

```
void binary_print(unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int mask;       // Use a bit mask starting from the highest bit
    for (mask = 0x8000000000; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
    {
        if (mask & 0x80808080) // output a space every 8 bits
            printf(" ");
        if (value & mask)    // If the bit in value is set,
            printf("1");     // print a 1.
        else
            printf("0");     // Otherwise, print a 0.
    }
}
```

With this approach, you could easily group bits in a different way, eg: `if (mask & 0x00808080)` would avoid printing the initial space, `if (mask & 0x08888888)` would output 8 groups of 4 bits.

Note also that all 3 `printf` calls could be changed to calls to `putchar` with the appropriate character constant.